How to append conditional className in Next.js?
This is my button:
<button
        className="inline-flex items-center justify-center w-9 h-9 border-0 outline-0 bg-transparent cursor-pointer
        hover:bg-vivense-gray-100 transition ease-in-out duration-300"
        disabled={disabledIncrementButton}
        onClick={increment}
        
      >

I want to add bg-vivense-gray-100 to className according to the value "disabledIncrementButton".
For example, if disabledIncrementButton is true, then add bg-vivense-gray-100 to className;
<button
        **className={`inline-flex items-center justify-center w-9 h-9 border-0 outline-0 bg-transparent cursor-pointer
        hover:bg-vivense-gray-100 transition ease-in-out duration-300` ${disabledIncrementButton} ?? bg-vivense-gray-100}**
        disabled={disabledIncrementButton}
        onClick={increment}
    
      >


Note that if you are using tailwind, dynamically composed classes won't be working.

@SyndRain thanks.  this answer for the question you shared works. Also,  given style to a component crushes on class attributes. So, i can add the following code also
style={disabledDecrementButton ? { backgroundColor: "#f5f5f5" } : {}}

Conditionally applying class attributes in react
here the answer. Also,
style={disabledDecrementButton ? { backgroundColor: "#f5f5f5" } : {}}

this works
